# gStreamer Video Recording Memory Leak

Tags: memory-leaks, video-streaming, gstreamer, video-recording

HI I am trying to record rtsp stream coming from camera(H264 format).

I am using following gst command to do recording in MPEG4 Format

```
gst-launch -e rtspsrc location=rtsp://10.17.8.136/mediainput/h264 latency=100 ! decodebin ! ffenc_mpeg4 ! avimux ! filesink location=test.mp4
```

and H264 format

```
gst-launch-0.10  -e rtspsrc location="rtsp://10.17.8.136/mediainput/h264" latency=100 ! rtph264depay byte-stream=false ! capsfilter caps="video/x-h264,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=(fraction)25/1" ! mp4mux ! filesink location=testh264.mp4
```

Both are doing recording but i have observed that There is RAM mermory is gradually increasing.

Does gStreamer has memory leak. or there is problem in my pipeline command?

Answer (score 1):

That is not a leak, the mp4 muxer is building the index table in memory, before writing it out to disk on eos.

Comment: whats should i do to avoid this?

Comment: Huh? You can't really avoid it. When you stop the recording the memory will be released. How much is the increase per minute?

Comment: That I didnt measure. It increases gradually. my application demands 24*7 working. so it will crash down once RAM is full. Can you suggest alternative solutions?

Comment: Maybe you could give more details what you want to do. If you want to record something for 24*7 also your disk will become full at some point. If you want to stream video you'd use the streamable=TRUE on mp4mux. avi is not streamable.

Comment: Disk may be full in not any issue. Problem is with RAM memory increasing while recording 24*7.System will crash down once RAM is full due.

Comment: Please learn more about the file-formats you are using before you claim that there is a memory leak. Please also try what I suggested in the previous comment. If you want to record a really long file and the file needs to be seekable, buy more ram.

Comment: Dear Friend,  You may be not understand my query. I am not claiming there is memory leak in GStreamer. I have use set of Gst command to record a Mpeg4 and H264 stream.When recording is doing my PC RAM memory is keep increasing.  Thats because you as suggest  mp4 muxer is building the index table in memory. How can one use more RAM? I have enough RAM(4GB) for that application. you may be thinking about Harddrive where video is writing,isnt it?. I agree hard drive may full once we keep recording Video Data. But RAM has to be constant.

Comment: Actaully I am fresher in Gstreamer. Can you elaborate more on  your answer?

Comment: C'mon. Try "mp4mux streamable=True" in the pipeline above.